# "Exception in thread" error when updating key-value pair in a Flask app

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm building a basic chatting program (Flack from CS50s web programming).

I have a dictionary where I'm storing channels & messages as key value pairs.

The messages are in a list so one key value pair would look like:

`{"channelExample" : ["msg1", "msg2"]}`.

I also have another variable that keeps track of the current room/channel the user is messaging in called **currentRoom**.

When a user submits a message, I'm attempting to update the messages in that channel by doing the following (*emit* is already imported & I've confirmed that **currentRoom** & the input message are string values):

```py
@socketio.on("submit message")
def submitMessage(message):
    channels[currentRoom].append(message)
    emit("display message", message)
```

However I am being thrown an "**Exception in thread...**" error for `channels[currentRoom].append(message)`& I'm not sure why.

My full code in Flask:

```py
import os

from flask import Flask, session, render_template, url_for, request, flash, redirect, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit, join_room, leave_room


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
socketio = SocketIO(app)

currentRoom = None
channels = {}

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("welcome.html", channels=channels)

@socketio.on("new channel")
def newChannel(channelName):
    # Store new channel to keep track of it
    channels.update( {channelName : []} )

@socketio.on("retrieve channels") 
def retrieveChannels():
    channelNames = []

    for channel in channels:
        channelNames.append(channel)

        emit("providing channels", channelNames)

@socketio.on("retrieve messages")    
def loadMessages(channelName):
    currentRoom = channelName

    channelMessages = channels[currentRoom]

    emit("load messages", channelMessages)

@socketio.on("submit message")
def submitMessage(message):
    channels[currentRoom].append(message)
    emit("display message", message)
```

Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    // Connect to websocket
    var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

    // When connected, 
    socket.on('connect', () => {

        var nameInput = document.querySelector("#usernameInput");
        var welcomeMessage = document.querySelector("#welcomeMessage");
        var createChannel = document.querySelector("#createChannel");
        var newChannelForm = document.querySelector("#newChannelForm");
        var newMessageForm = document.querySelector("#newMessageForm");

        function userExists() {
            // Check if user has come here before
            if (localStorage.getItem("username")) {
                // Display a welcome message
                welcomeMessage.innerHTML = `Welcome back ${localStorage.getItem("username")}!`;
                nameInput.style.display = "none";
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        };

        function createChannelBtn(name) {
            // Create new channel & style it
            let newChannel = document.createElement("button");
            newChannel.id = name;
            newChannel.innerHTML = name;
            newChannel.className = "btn btn-block btn-outline-dark";
            newChannel.style.display = "block";

            // Attach to current list 
            document.querySelector("#channels").appendChild(newChannel);

            // When someone clicks the channel
            newChannel.onclick = () => {

                newChannel.classList.toggle("active");

                socket.emit("retrieve messages", newChannel.id);
                console.log("Retrieving messages!!!");

                socket.on("load messages", channelMessages => {
                    console.log("loading messages!");
                    for (let i = 0; i < channelMessages.length; i++) {
                        createMessage(channelMessages[i]);
                    }
                });

            };
        };

        function createMessage(messageContent) {
            let message = document.createElement("h6");
            message.innerHTML = messageContent;
            document.querySelector("#messageWindow").appendChild(message);
            console.log("Currently creating message!");
        };

        function loadChannels() {
            socket.emit("retrieve channels")

            socket.on("providing channels", channelNames => {
                for (let i = 0; i < channelNames.length; i++) {
                    createChannelBtn(channelNames[i]);
                }
            });
        };

        // Make sure the new channel form is not displayed until "Create channel" button is clicked
        newChannelForm.style.display = "none";

        // Check if user exists already in local storage
        userExists();

        loadChannels();

        // If someone submits a username...
        nameInput.addEventListener("click", () => {
            // if that username exists, do nothing
            if (userExists()) {
            }
            // else remember the username
            else {
                localStorage.setItem("username", document.querySelector("#user").value);
            }
        });

        // When someone wants to create a channel
        createChannel.addEventListener("click", () => {
            // Show form
            newChannelForm.style.display = "block";

            // When user inputs new channel name...
            newChannelForm.onsubmit = () => {

                // Retrieve their input
                var newChannelName = document.querySelector("#newChannel").value;

                // Create a new channel
                createChannelBtn(newChannelName);

                // Notify server to store new channel 
                socket.emit("new channel", newChannelName);

                // Clear input field
                document.querySelector("#newChannel").innerHTML = "";

                return false;

            };
        });

        newMessageForm.onsubmit = () => {
            let message = document.querySelector("#newMessage").value;
            console.log("You have entered " + message);

            socket.emit("submit message", message);
            console.log("Submitted message!");

            socket.on("display message", message => {
                createMessage(message);
                console.log("Displaying message!!");
            });

            return false;
        };

    });

    // DOM Ending Bracket
});
```

Comment: You haven't provided `welcome.html`, which makes it hard to debug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time, post the full traceback, as well as all necessary files, as it will make it easier to debug your code. You say you verified that `currentRoom` is a string value, but perhaps only when receiving it from the browser. You don't check that in your `submitMessage()` function, and then you try to access your list of channels using `None`, as shown by the traceback which looks something like this:

```py
Exception in thread Thread-13:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Michael\Desktop\sandbox\sandbox\lib\site-packages\socketio\server.py", line 640, in _handle_event_internal
    r = server._trigger_event(data[0], namespace, sid, *data[1:])
  File "c:\Users\Michael\Desktop\sandbox\sandbox\lib\site-packages\socketio\server.py", line 669, in _trigger_event
    return self.handlers[namespace][event](*args)
  File "c:\Users\Michael\Desktop\sandbox\sandbox\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 280, in _handler
    *args)
  File "c:\Users\Michael\Desktop\sandbox\sandbox\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 694, in _handle_event
    ret = handler(*args)
  File "c:\Users\Michael\Desktop\sandbox\sandbox.py", line 47, in submitMessage
    channels[currentRoom].append(message)
KeyError: None
```

That should alert you that your main concern is a [`KeyError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError), which is happening because you're passing in `None` to your `channels` dict, which means that `currentRoom` must be none.

So why is it happening? The issue lies on line 34:

```py
32  @socketio.on("retrieve messages")    
33  def loadMessages(channelName):
34      currentRoom = channelName  # <--- Issue here
35  
36      channelMessages = channels[currentRoom]
37  
38      emit("load messages", channelMessages)
```

Python variables follow the [LEGB rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules), which means when resolving a variable name, the interpreter will first check the **L**ocal scope, then the **E**nclosing scope, then the **G**lobal scope, and finally the **B**uilt-in scope. However, when you **assign** a variable in a certain scope, Python will create the variable within that scope.

So, you've now created a new variable named `currentRoom`, which is a **separate** variable from the `currentRoom` defined at the top, and is only visible within the `loadMessages()` function! So, how do you let Python know that you are referring to that global variable when you assign within a function?

You use the `global` keyword:

```py
@socketio.on("retrieve messages")    
def loadMessages(channelName):
    global currentRoom  # <--- This tells Python that `currentRoom` is a global variable
    currentRoom = channelName  # Assign to the global variable

    channelMessages = channels[currentRoom]

    emit("load messages", channelMessages)
```

Now, when we call `submitMessage()`, `currentRoom` now has an actual text value rather than just `None`, and the function succeeds without any error.

Comment: I apologize for forgetting to put the HTML file in. Thank you so much though, that was what I didn't do.